# Float: right dropping text down in FF

Tags: css, firefox, css-float

I have a title bar in ExtJs which has a div with the username in it. I want it to appear on the right side of the title bar which I can get it to do with 'float: right;' but in FF it drops the text down a line where as it's fine in Chrome?

HTML:

```
<span unselectable="on" class="x-panel-header-text x-panel-header-text-default" id="programList_header_hd-textEl">Program Access permissions (TestResetValidity)<div class="programusername">Test Reset Validity</div></span>
```

CSS:

```
.programusername {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 70px;
}
```

[image]

How can I get them lined up like this in all browsers not just chrome (below)?

[image]

Comment: Because you have `position:relative` on `.programusername`, you can change `margin-right:70px;` to `right:70px;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, never put a block element like `div` in an inline element like `span`.

You can put the right text in another div and put it after `div#programusername` and this will fix it.

Also, there is no need to change the position to relative.

At the end, put a `<div style="clear: both;">` after the elements that you are lining with float to prevent displacing other page elements.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `overflow: hidden;` to the parent `<span>`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.programusername {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 70px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```